# How do I write a logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic, model

I am trying to write a logistic regression model, the response is binary, and these are the parameters: Xi1, Xi2, Xi1∗Xi1, Xi1∗Xi2, Xi2∗Xi2 and sex.

I am uncertain how this should be done. Is it simpler than I am thinking?

Comment: To generate more interest, give some more detail by editing your post and giving the goals of the analysis, the type of data you have, sample size, etc., and state which learning resources you are using to introduce yourself to logistic regression.

Comment: If you did the regression on only $X_1$ and sex, you would wind up with $log\bigg(\dfrac{p_i}{1-p_i}\bigg) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} + \beta_2sex_i$. Do you see how to add the additional variables?

Comment: This is essentially the same, as your [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439560/how-do-i-write-a-mixed-effect-regression-model-mrm/439647#439647) - just don't add the random effects. Follow the comment by @Dave and what I showed you in the other question.